# Reinstalling all packages installed from an old repository that exist in a new repository (Apt)

Tags: debian, apt

My base system is Debian and came with ftp.debian.org in the sources.list file.
I have since added the latest Ubuntu repositories to my sources.list file and taken out the original Debian one.

Unfortunately all the packages I installed with the Debian repository that also exist in the Ubuntu repositories do not get replaced with an apt update, upgrade, dist-upgrade or full-upgrade.

So how can I force the reinstallation of currently installed packages from the old and removed repository with ones that exist in the new repositories?

Comment: Debian is not Ubuntu, and vice versa. If you want to switch from Debian to Ubuntu, you should re-install your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A safer alternative would be to save the output of `dpkg --get-selections`, reinstall the machine with Ubuntu, and then use `dpkg --set-selections` to install the same set of packages on Ubuntu.

It's possible to get apt to do what you want.  **But first a warning: this type of change can easily leave you with a system that won't boot or is broken in other subtle or not-so-subtle ways.**  You should be fully prepared to either fix difficult problems or do a reinstall and restore data from backups.

You need to create an apt pin for Ubuntu packages with a priority at least 1000.  This allows apt to install the Ubuntu version even if it means downgrading.  Create `/etc/apt/preferences.d/ubuntu` with this content:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

You should update `/etc/apt/sources.list`, install the `ubuntu-keyring` package manually, and run `apt update`.  (Sounds like you've already done these steps.)  Then you can try an `apt full-upgrade` to move all packages to the Ubuntu versions.

Remove `/etc/apt/preferences.d/ubuntu` when you're done.

Note that Debian and Ubuntu use different naming for the Linux kernel meta-package, so you'll need to manually uninstall the Debian one (e.g., `linux-image-amd64`), install the Ubuntu one (e.g., `linux-image-generic`), and maybe manually remove the Debian `linux-image-*-amd64` packages.